# All subdomains point to default site

Tags: wagtail

I was working on Wagtail page with two sites - www and blog. Locally both sites were working like a charm. I had domains www.local and blog.local and they were pointing to proper sites.
After going live, all subdomains are pointing to default site. If there is no default site, I keep getting 404. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: As it turned out I forgot to add this to my nginx config:

`proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: Would be great if you posted that as the answer and marked it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't Wagtail's issue. I forgot to add `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in my nginx config.